# Show that $f(x)=x^3+(2+i)x+(1+i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Problem says:

> Show that $f(x)=x^3+(2+i)x+(1+i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$.

I think I have to use Eisenstein's criterion with substituting $x$ with something   but for me to show that the conditions are satisfied is hard

Comment: It's a cubic, so you only need to show that it has no linear factor.

Comment: You are probably familiar with the Rational Roots Theorem. An analogous result holds in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: So, it suffices to show that $f(₩pm (1+i))$ is nonzero. Is it okay?

Comment: Unfortunately it is more unpleasant than that, for we have to rule out $1,-1,i,-i$ and $1+i$ and its three relatives. So it might be worthwhile to see whether a simple transformation allows Eisenstein to go through.